# Use jQuery to hide an HTML element after a certain height is scrolled beyond

Tags: jquery, show-hide, sticky-footer, sticky

I'm trying to prototype something here for a presentation.

I'd like it work like this:

- When the viewport is less than 900px tall there is a fixed position footer attached to the base of the page.

  - Once the SCROLL position on the page passes a certain threshold, this footer get's hidden
- When the viewport is larger than 900px, this it will behave just like a normal page... the footer will appear after the content.

I'm just prototyping this with background images. I'm essentially trying to do what you see in iOS Contacts app (The letter you're viewing sticks until you scroll past it then it moves up), only I'm doing it on the bottom not the top. Has anyone done this in the browser?

I can show/hide the sticky footer based on viewport size with media queries, but I don't know how to do the same thing with scroll position.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var $win = $(window);
   var scrollTopThreshold = 200;
   if($win.height() < 900){//first condition
      //position the footer to the base of the page using css or jquery
   }
   else if($(document).scrollTop() > scrollTopThreshold){//second condition
      //Hide the footer
   }
   else if($win.height() > 900){//thrid condition
      //let footer appear at the bottom of the content
   }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get the .scrollTop() > scrollTopThreshold. Don't suppose you could do a quick demo? =)

Comment: I have declared a local variable for scroll top threshold. Set whatever threshold value you need in this variable.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding what ".scrollTop()" is, to calculate against.

Comment: If I could simplify this into simply hiding an element when the user has scrolled N number of pixels, how might I do that?

Comment: Then use just the second condition and set the N number of pixel value in scrollTopThreshold variable.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just having a hard time getting this to work in the code. It *sort of works*. Were you able to get it working?